# ebay API setNotificationPreferences

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I am trying to set up notifications to an endpoint in my PHP application using the ebay Api Trading call for [getNotificationPreferences](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetNotificationPreferences.html). I'm finding this extremely frustrating and I am a little unnerved by the lack of examples around the web for a sample XML body to send. I have read their docs and tried to follow all eBay's own examples. Using their [test tool](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/?index=0&api=trading&call=GetNotificationPreferences&variation=xml) I get errors even with their sample snippet, some of which include: "Unrecognized element <ApplicationDeliveryPreferences>" and Unrecognized element <PreferenceLevel>

Really, if I could just see an example of ONE working call that sets up a notification to a url when an item is sold I can surely take it from there. I know it is not my user token because I have used both my sandbox token and my production token. Someone help me, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up notifications in Developer site account settings before sending in my first GetNotificationPreferencesRequest. Go to your account, click the notifications link next to the App-ID. I think you need to indicate your web server is ready here before notifications will work, I'm not sure if you can do it all through the api. After that I was able to set my preferences with:

```
<GetNotificationPreferencesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">

<ApplicationDeliveryPreferences>
    <AlertEnable>Enable</AlertEnable>
    <ApplicationEnable>Enable</ApplicationEnable>
    <ApplicationURL>http://YOUR-SITE.com/webhook.php</ApplicationURL>
    <DeviceType>Platform</DeviceType>
</ApplicationDeliveryPreferences>

<UserDeliveryPreferenceArray>
    <NotificationEnable>
        <EventType>ItemSold</EventType>
        <EventEnable>Enable</EventEnable>
    </NotificationEnable>
</UserDeliveryPreferenceArray>

<!-- repeat UserDeliveryPreferenceArray for each notification wanted -->

</GetNotificationPreferencesRequest>
```

Comment: i finally after much trial and tribulation did get this to work back in May and I used this method. Thanks!